# How to find the max/min of a nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to find the maximum of a nested array, something like this:

```
a = [[1,2],[20,3]]
d3.max(d3.max(a)) // 20
```

but my array contains a text field that I want to discard:

```
a = [["yz",1,2],["xy",20,3]]
d3.max(a) // 20
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you have a nested array of numbers (`arrays = [[1, 2], [20, 3]]`), nest [d3.max](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_max):

```
var max = d3.max(arrays, function(array) {
  return d3.max(array);
});
```

Or equivalently, use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var max = d3.max(arrays.map(function(array) {
  return d3.max(array);
}));
```

If you want to ignore string values, you can use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to ignore strings:

```
var max = d3.max(arrays, function(array) {
  return d3.max(array.filter(function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number";
  }));
});
```

Alternatively, if you know the string is always in the first position, you could use [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which is a bit more efficient:

```
var max = d3.max(arrays, function(array) {
  return d3.max(array.slice(1));
});
```

Yet another option is to use an accessor function which returns `NaN` for values that are not numbers. This will cause d3.max to ignore those values. Conveniently, JavaScript's built-in `Number` function does exactly this, so you can say:

```
var max = d3.max(arrays, function(array) {
  return d3.max(array, Number);
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem but when I try to apply the array filter but I have the following error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'array.filter(function(value) 
  {
    return typeof value === "number";
    })'). My scene variable is an array of objects loaded from a json. What is wrong ?

Comment: and with arrow function notation, which are perfect for when you are passing short functions as arguments: 
var max = d3.max(arrays, a => d3.max(a));
and to filter strings:
var max = d3.max(arrays, a => d3.max(a.filter(v => typeof v === "number")));

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
function arrmax(arrs) {
    var toplevel = [];

    var f = function(v) {
        return !isNaN(v);
    };

    for (var i = 0, l = arrs.length; i<l; i++) {
        toplevel.push(Math.max.apply(window, arrs[i].filter(f)));
    }
    return Math.max.apply(window, toplevel);
}
```

or better:

```
function arrmax(arrs) {
    if (!arrs || !arrs.length) return undefined;
    var max = Math.max.apply(window, arrs[0]), m,
        f = function(v){ return !isNaN(v); };
    for (var i = 1, l = arrs.length; i<l; i++) {
        if ((m = Math.max.apply(window, arrs[i].filter(f)))>max) max=m;
    }
    return max;
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for Array.filter method details.

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten an array and apply a function to each member

```
Array.prototype.flatten= function(fun){
    if(typeof fun!= 'function') fun= '';
    var A= [], L= this.length, itm;
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(itm!= undefined){
            if(!itm.flatten){
                if(fun) itm= fun(itm);
                if(itm) A.push(itm);
            }
            else A= A.concat(itm.flatten(fun));
        }
    }
    return A;
}

var a= [["yz", 1, 2], ["xy", 20, 3]], max=-Infinity;

var max=Math.max.apply(a, a.flatten(Number));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you now exactly what columns you want to test, you can use:

```
var columns = ["ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC"];

var max = selectedMax(columns,dataset);
var min = selectedMin(columns,dataset)

function selectedMax(columns, dataset) {
    var max;
    columns.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        var tmpmax = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
            return +d[element];
        });       
        max = (tmpmax > max || max === undefined) ? tmpmax : max;
    });
    return max;
}

function selectedMin(columns, dataset) {
    var min;
    columns.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        var tmpmin = d3.min(dataset, function(d) {
            return +d[element];
        });
        min = (tmpmin < min || min === undefined) ? tmpmin : min;
    });  
return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a cruel hack, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/core/max.js) for `d3.max`, your best bet might be to define a `d3.max1` that discards the first element by copying that code, but replacing `i=-1` with `i=0`. The code at that link is excerpted here. Note that I'm not a regular d3.js user, but from what I know of the library, you're going to want make sure your version has an `f.call` case like this function does, so that it can respond to live updates correctly.

```
d3.max = function(array, f) {
  var i = -1,
      n = array.length,
      a,
      b;
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    while (++i < n && ((a = array[i]) == null || a != a)) a = undefined;
    while (++i < n) if ((b = array[i]) != null && b > a) a = b;
  } else {
    while (++i < n && ((a = f.call(array, array[i], i)) == null || a != a)) a = undefined;
    while (++i < n) if ((b = f.call(array, array[i], i)) != null && b > a) a = b;
  }
  return a;
};
```

Then it would just be `d3.max(d3.max1(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

[`d3.array`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) provides [`d3.merge`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#merge) which flattens an array of arrays.

Coupled with [`d3.max`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#max) and javascript's `Number` as an accessor:

```
var max = d3.max(d3.merge(arrays), Number);
```

For example:

```js
var input = [["yz", 1, 2], ["xy", 20, 3]];

var max = d3.max(d3.merge(input), Number);

console.log(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v2.min.js"></script>
```