# Find the maximum value in an object where the keys are arrays?

Tags: d3.js

Using D3, how can I find the maximum value in an object where all the values are arrays of floats?

```
  var data = {
    "point1": { 
       "level1": [...],
       "level2": [...]
    },
    ...
  };
```

I read [Mike's answer on finding the max of a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564441/how-to-find-the-max-min-of-a-nested-array-in-javascript), but I'm not sure what to do here since this is an object of arrays.

Currently I'm doing this, which is awful:

```
  var c1Max = d3.max(data.point1.level1, function(d) { return d.value; });
  var c2Max = d3.max(data.point1.level2, function(d) { return d.value; });
  var c3Max = d3.max(data.point2.level1, function(d) { return d.value; });
  var c4Max = d3.max(data.point2.level2, function(d) { return d.value; });
  var c5Max = d3.max(data.point3.level1, function(d) { return d.value; });
  var c6Max = d3.max(data.point3.level2, function(d) { return d.value; });
  var max = d3.max([c1Max, c2Max, c3Max, c4Max, c5Max, c6Max]);
```

Maybe I should iterate over all the keys? Or maybe I could flatten the `data` object somehow? Or maybe there's a nicer way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`d3.entries`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_entries) to convert the object into something you can iterate over:

```
var max = d3.max(d3.entries(data), function(d) {
    return d3.max(d3.entries(d.value), function(e) {
        return d3.max(e.value);
    });
});
```

In this particular case (keys not required) you can of course also use [`d3.values`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_values), which makes the above code a bit shorter.

To make it work with the structure in your jsfiddle, you need this code:

```
var max1 = d3.max(d3.entries(data), function(d) {
  return d3.max(d3.entries(d.value), function(e) {
      return d3.max(e.value, function(f) { return f.value; });
  });
});
```

Comment: That edit returns an object... here is a JSFiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/xvtrS/

Comment: Ok, this is slightly different from the structure you've described in your question. Editing again.